# Avoiding loop when at run-time parse a javascript code

Tags: javascript, parsing, loops, eval

I realized a javascript parser built in a web page.
A user can put a javascript code in the text-area like:

```
var i = 0;
i++;
var y = i * 10;
document.write(y);
```

that is parsed in order to generate some outputs (e.g., document.write stream, and so on).

The function *parse* is called when textarea *change* event is generated.

```
function parse(text) {
    try {
        ....
        eval(text);
    } catch (e) {
        ....
        return {
            status : false, output : ..., ... : ...
        };
    }
    return {
        status : true, output : ...., ... : ...
    };
}
```

Everything works well but I have problem when a user writes a loop in the text area (e.g., `for(var i=0; i<10; )`, `while(true)`)
because the application goes in loop.

To avoid this problem, I would ask you all some questions/solutions for this problem:

1. Are there some javascript libraries or functions that allow to
   `eval` a javascript code but are loop-free?
2. Can I ask to execute my parse function but in a fixed time? After such time I would generate an exception that stops the eval function.
3. Before to call the `eval(text)` I can call a `checkIfThereAreLoops` function that analyses the text seeking for patterns like `for(var i=0; i<10; )` or `while(true)`. Is this a good solution? Can I use a regular expression to seek these patterns?

Comment: Try to avoid eval, it said bad things about you

Comment: why not simply validate the input and forbid (ignore or notify the user) these malicious actions?

Comment: @EliranMalka — "simply"?!

Comment: @EliranMalka - the 'simply validation' of the code is something like I described in point 3?

Comment: Can I force the stop of the `eval` method after a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to see whether arbitrary code will terminate, you will be in for a rough time [the Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

So you are right to think that you would either need a preventative measure on your parse function that either times out or dismisses unsafe input.

I'm not aware of a way to interrupt `eval` without the browser imposing a 'this script is running too long' limit, so you would want to sanitize the input and not evaluate anything with a loop: This will be tricky since you can't just search for constructs such as `for, while` etc and avoid recursive function calls.

This is a difficult problem to solve...

One 'hacky' solution could be to insert a *unique* variable declaration into the top of the entered code (hidden of course) and to increment this variable every other line from within the input code (again, hide these insertions and allow for syntax constructs becoming broken. Also insert sanity checks at each increment `if unique_var > 99999 exit;` (where 99999 is some limit you impose).

This should at least stop infinite loops.

Comment: So I know the halting problem so I'm trying to find an efficient solution to avoid this basic loop.

Thus if I have a variable `_op_counter = 0` before to call the `eval` function I can add the code `incrementOpCounter()` 

`function incrementOpCounter(){
if _op_counter > 99999 throw "There is a loop.";
_op_counter++;
}`

to each line I could resolve the problem. 

The new code before to be parsed is (see example)
`var i = 0; incrementOpCounter();
i++; incrementOpCounter();
var y = i * 10; incrementOpCounter();
document.write(y); incrementOpCounter();`

Comment: But I can have some problem with [`if`, `while`, `for`] without `{}` but could be a solution...